# Executing batch file from sql server job

Tags: batch, sql-server

I want to create backup job on sql server. And i want to execute batch file in job. I just wonder the part of executing batch file from sql job. Do you have any idea?

Any help would appreciated.

```
use MyDb
go

BACKUP DATABASE MyDb TO DISK = 'C:\BackUps\MyDb.bak' WITH differential 
go

-- Call my batch file (which will zip MyDb.bak file)
```

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 1):

If you do this is as a SQL Server Agent job (from SSMS) it makes calling batch files a lot easier. Just add a step of type "`Operating System (CmdExec)`" and point it to your .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using besides sql server 2008 enterprise (or above) then [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046%28SQL.105%29.aspx) is the way to do it, although you'll have to enable it first with [sp_configure.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693%28SQL.105%29.aspx)

If you are lucky enough to be on mssql 2008 enterprise then the [backup compression feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719.aspx) is what you should be using.

You may want to do something a bit more advanced then calling a static.bat file.
Here are some useful samples:
[Sample sql script to zip and transfer database backup file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128166/sample-sql-script-to-zip-and-transfer-database-backup-file)
[How to take SQL database backup in .zip format](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/0c6aa82a-1a49-4480-9181-6121bcbcd18a)